# Tips on stubbing a helper method from a rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a unique scenario. I am using Rspec 3 and Capybara to run some rspec tests, and I need to stub out method calls to return true/false based on certain tests.

my test is in spec/features/landing_page_spec.rb

I have a test:

```
describe "a logged in user with a pending application" do
  before do
    allow_any_instance_of(UserApplicationInfo).to receive(:has_pending_application?).and_return(true)
    allow(ApplicationController).to receive(:logged_in?).and_return(true)
    visit '/'
  end
```

I have a helper method in app/controllers/helpers/logins_helper.rb

```
module LoginsHelper
  def logged_in?
    current_user.present?
  end
end
```

and I have a view views/landing_page/index.html.erb which has the following snippet

```
<% if logged_in? && @user.account_id %>
   I want this
<% else %>
   I dont want this
<% end %>
```

I am not able to stub out the helper method `logged_in?`. I AM able to stub the method when I am in the controller. For example, when I put a `pry` in landing_page_controller I get the following:

```
[1] pry(#<LandingPageController>)> logged_in?
=> true
[4] pry(#<LandingPageController>)> self.class
=> LandingPageController
[1] pry(#<LandingPageController>)> self.class.superclass
=> ApplicationController
```

And when I put a `pry` in the view/landing_page/index.html.erb

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x74ad8>>)> logged_in?
=> false
[3] pry(#<#<Class:0x74ad8>>)> self.class
=> #<Class:0x74ad8>
[4] pry(#<#<Class:0x74ad8>>)> self.class.superclass
=> ActionView::Base
```

Now I understand that the reason why logged_in? is returning true in the controller is because It inherits from ApplicationController. It doesn't seem like ActionView::base does. But I have tried code such as:

```
allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:logged_in?).and_return(true)
allow_any_instance_of(ActionView::Base).to receive(:logged_in?).and_return(true)
```

But no luck. I have also read up on [stubbing a helper method](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-0/docs/view-specs/view-spec#passing-view-spec-that-stubs-a-helper-method) but I cannot access the `view` object because this isn't a view spec. I wish it was that easy. If there is a way to implicitly define the view object that would be awesome.

I have searched extensively on this subject, and perhaps the consensus is to use cucumber and manually log in the user. OR run this spec in a view. If there are any tips on how to run the helper method in a view and test it. I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You probably want to actually log in, and set `current_user`. It seems like your views must assume that if `logged_in?` returns true, they can safely access `current_user`, so you're just going to get a bunch of `NoMethod` errors when you try to invoke methods on `current_user`.

Comment: What meagar said. These are integration tests, and should be run as though there's a user on the system--by putting a user in the system.

Comment: Understood, I had a feeling that this was necessary. Is it appropriate to run Rspec/Capybara for integration tests? Or should I be using Cucumber?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I don't see the reasoning in your writeup anywhere.

Comment: I was looking to test something like: If a new user views the home page they should see XYZ. If an existing user views the home page, they should see ABC. If an existing user with certain attributes views the home page they should see 123. Something like that. Perhaps view specs are more appropriate

Comment: Using RSpec with Capybara is totally appropriate for integration tests. If you want something more focused, I would recommend moving the logic out of your view template to somewhere easier to test. If you really want to write a view spec, you can stub the helper with https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-1/docs/view-specs/view-spec#passing-view-spec-that-stubs-a-helper-method